# keep my css popup open until i click outside of the popup

Tags: css

I'm trying to keep my css popup window open so anyone can copy text from the popup window but everytime any mouse click happens the popup closes... how can i keep it open unless the mouse clicks outside the popup window?

ive tried to add:

```
a.tooltip-reports:active { display: block; }
```

but this didnt work....

my css:

```
 /* click tooltip : reports.php */
a.tooltip-reports { cursor:pointer; outline:none; }
a.tooltip-reports strong { line-height:16px; }
a.tooltip-reports:focus { text-decoration:none;}
a.tooltip-reports span { z-index:10; display:none; padding:10px 10px; margin-top:25px; margin-left:-165px; width:270px; line-height:16px; } 
a.tooltip-reports:focus span{ text-align:left; display:inline; word-wrap: break-word; position:absolute; border:2px solid #FFF; color:#EEE; background:#000; width:270px; } 
.callout-reports { z-index:20; position:absolute; border:0; top:-14px; left:135px; } 
/*CSS3 extras*/ 
a.tooltip-reports span { border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px #666; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px #666; box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px #666; opacity: 0.95; }
```

Comment: You probably need to use JavaScript.

Comment: really? i thought this could be done with straight css... hmmm

Comment: I also think JavaScript is necessary. Maybe you should post a JSFiddle or something so we can *see* what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: i think i will try to use jquery bPopup plugin...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `:target` selector. [Mozilla has an example of doing basically what you want here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget#Creating_a_pure_CSS_.22lightbox.22)

`:target` is a pseudo class that styles the target element with the ID of whatever has been linked to via the hash symbol `#`.

[It is supported in the major browsers. It is not supported in IE8 (or below) and has partial support in IE9+.](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#link5)